# additional bundles for tycho surefire

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-surefire-plugin, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

My tycho surefire test application requires more bundles than which are automatically added through tycho dependency handling.

I could add all bundles as `Require-Bundle` in the `MANIFEST.MF` of the test bundle, but this seems like not a very clean solution.

I would prefer to add a feature to the `tycho-surefire-plugin` configuration, where all bundles of the feature will be automatically added to the:

> target/work/configuration/config.ini  **osgi.bundles**

Is it possible to add a feature or otherwise a list of additional bundles?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add them as required bundles, you can "enrich" the target platform for the test project by using ["Extra Requirements"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Extra_requirements) in the `target-platform-configuration` of the test project.

For example, something like

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <dependency-resolution>
      <extraRequirements>
        <requirement>
          <type>eclipse-feature</type>
          <id>example.project.feature</id>
          <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
        </requirement>
      </extraRequirements>
    </dependency-resolution>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

In this example, you're adding an Eclipse feature (by the way, this is also the only way to have a feature when running Tycho surefire), an Eclipse plugin, etc.

Remember, this will affect only the current test project.